# I feel like this cannot be proven. Am I setting up the contrapositive correctly?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, formal-proofs

The question ask:

*Use proof by contrapositive to show that if a positive integer is the product of  two distinct primes, then its square root is irrational.*

So I have not(q) -> not(p) as follows:

*If the square root of a positive integer is rational then it is not the product of two distinct primes.*

One issue I have is I think I have already found a counter example that goes against this.

Lets say the positive integer was 36.

The Square root of 36 is 6, which is rational.

The prime factorization for 36 would be. 2 * 2 * 3 * 3.

Which would mean it has 2 distinct primes of 2 and 3.

Did I go somewhere wrong with my setup of the contrapositive or my understanding of what 2 distinct primes means?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would read "product of two distinct primes" as having prime factors p and q, and no others, so 35 (5 * 7), etc.

Comment: Thanks. I will try and approach the problem that way and see if I have any luck.